# Unity3d взаимодействие скриптов и переменных

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-faq

Суть вопроса такая как взаимодействие привести две переменных разных скриптов.
имеем объект "очков" на нем висит скрипт в котором идет подбор очков через онтригер
есть объект "труба" на котором висит скрипт со скоростью перемещения
в обоих скриптах переменные публичные

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Tube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedTube = 2f;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left*speedTube * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

и скрипт очков

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;    
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tube Turbo;        
    public int score;
    public Text scoreText;
    public void Start()
    {
       score = 0;
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        if (score >= 1)
        {
           Turbo.speedTube = Turbo.speedTube(speedTube) * 2;       
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Score" )
        {
            score++;
        }            
    }
}
```

хочу ускорить движение труб про достижении определенных очков , допустим 5. как делать такую функцию я знаю ,  помощью конструкции if, но не могу получить переменную с класс Tube и положить в нее новое значение.
в документации я почитал не понял если честно, там не описан такой метод, там описано если два скрипта находятся на объекте, у меня Tube скрипт лежит на префабе, которые вызывается Instantiate в корутине в спаунс крипте, ну т.е отдельно
Не надо готовых решений, помогите как понять саму конструкцию действий с переменными из разных скриптом на разных объектах

не пинайте , только изучаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, вам нужно использовать `new`, но Unity не поддерживает это, вместо этого, Unity предлагает альтернативу:

Вам нужно создать публичную переменную скрипта, в котором хотите что-либо изменять:
`public Tube tb;`, в скрипте, из которого хотите изменять что-либо.

Далее, в эдиторе, а именно в инспекторе, у вас появится поле `tb` (Название может быть разным, в зависимости как вы назвали переменную), в это поле перенести объект, на котором у вас висит скрипт.

Всё, далее вы можете обращаться к `переменным`, `методам` и к всему, что находится в этом скрипте

Т.е. например: `tb.speedTube += 2;`

Answer (score -1):

Можно реализовать через static поля: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static
Сразу не скажу, будет ли находить переменную с префаба, даже если она static. Если не будет, то делайте через FindGameObjectWithTag.